# Reflection principles justifying $I2$ and larger cardinals

Tags: set-theory, large-cardinals

Consider the language of set theory together with the constant smybols $\langle \Omega_\alpha|\alpha\in Ord\rangle$. Let's add to $ZFC$ the axiom that for every $\alpha$,$n$ there is some $j: V_{\Omega_{\alpha+n}}\prec V_{\Omega_{\alpha+n+1}}$ with critical point $\Omega_\alpha$ and $j: (\Omega_{\alpha+i})=\Omega_{\alpha+i+1}$ for every $i\lt n$. This axiom is one of the strongest reflection principles I know of. It is significantly stronger than $I3$ for instance. However, even this reflection principle is weaker than $I2$.

There are (In my opinion, at least) strong arguments from reflection for $\Pi_n^m$-indescribable, supercompact, extendible, $n$-fold extendible (And by extension $n$-huge), and $I3$. However, even the incredibly strong axiom listed above is weaker than $I2$.

So what kind of reflection principles justify $I2$, $I1$, and $I0$ cardinals? In what way is the assertion that there is some $j: L(V_{\lambda+1})\prec L(V_{\lambda+1})$ a reflection principle? What are the arguements used to justify rank-into-rank axioms.

**Note:** I know about the answer that, due to Gödel's incompleteness theorem, we can never know if these axioms are consistent. I am not looking for answers like that, not because that position has no merit, but because it is obvious and well-known among set-theorists.

Comment: Why is this stronger than I3? I’m pretty sure it’s weaker than a 2-huge. Apply Rowbottom’s theorem to the measure derived from a 2-hugeness embedding to get a measure one set $X$ such that for all $\alpha<\beta$ in $X$, there is a hugeness ultrafilter with critical point $\alpha$ and target $\beta$.

Comment: Correction: It’s weaker than $\kappa$ that is $2^{\kappa}$-supercompact.  Let $j : V \to M$ witness this supercompacntess with critical point $\kappa$.  $M$ can see $j \restriction V_{\kappa+1}$.  Let $U$ be the measure on $\kappa$ derived from $j$.  Reflect to get $A \in U$ such that for all $\alpha \in A$, there is $j_\alpha : V_{\alpha+1} \to V_{\kappa+1}$, with critical point $\alpha$, $j(\alpha)=\kappa$.  Reflect again and use diagonal intersection to a measure one set $B \subseteq A$ witnessing your reflection principle.

Comment: Sorry, I misremembered the reflection principle. I have fixed it now.

Comment: I think what you have written now is weaker than I3.  Let $j : V_\lambda \to V_\lambda$ with critical sequence $\kappa_0,\kappa_1,...$, and let $U$ be the normal measure on $\kappa_0$ derived from $j$.  Then $A \in U$ iff for all $n>0$, $\{ \kappa_0,\dots,\kappa_{n-1}\} \subseteq j^n(A)$.  Let $H \in U$ be homogeneous with respect to the property that for $\alpha_0<...<\alpha_n$ in $A$, there is an embedding $j : V_{\alpha_{n-1}} \to V_{\alpha_n}$ with critical point $\alpha_0$ sending $\alpha_i$ to $\alpha_{i+1}$.  Then for all $n>0$, $\{ \kappa_0,\dots,\kappa_{n-1} \} \subseteq j^n(A)$.

Comment: I think it is stronger, because we can form an elementary chain $V_{\Omega_0}\prec V_{\Omega_1}\prec... V_\lambda$, where $\lambda=\sup\Omega_n$. Let $j_n: V_{\Omega_n}\prec V_{\Omega_{n+1}}$ witness the reflection principle for anay $n$. Then let $j(x)=j_n(x)$, where $n$ is the least ordinal such that $x\in V_{\Omega_n}$. Then $V_\lambda\vDash\phi(x)\leftrightarrow V_{\Omega_n}\vDash\phi(x)\leftrightarrow V_{\Omega_{n+1}}\vDash\phi(j(x))\leftrightarrow V_\lambda\vDash\phi(j(x))$, where $n$ is the least ordinal such that $x\in V_{\Omega_n}$. Therefore $j$ is an elementary embedding.

Comment: I don’t understand. It looks like your j could be the identity map. If not, you’ll have to be careful to make your embeddings coherent. Anyway, what’s the mistake in my argument?

Comment: $j$ cannot be the identity map, because $j(\Omega_0)=j_1(\Omega_0)=\Omega_1$. I'm not sure what you mean by coherent. $j((x,y))=j_n((x,y))=(j_n(x),j_n(y))$, where $n$ is the least ordinal such that $(x,y)\in\Omega_n$. So, for example if the least $n$ such that $x\in\Omega_n$ was $3$, and the least $n$ such that $y\in\Omega_n$ was $7$, then $j((x,y))=j_7((x,y))=(j_7(x),j_7(y))$.

Comment: As for the mistake in your argument, I'm not sure. What exactly do you mean by "homogeneous" (I'm sorry if this is obvious; I've simply never heard that term before)?

Comment: Use two colors on the finite subsets like I described. Rowbottom proved that measurable cardinals are Ramsey, which means there is a measure one set such that got all $n$, every size $n$ set gets the same color.

Comment: I’m skeptical of your composition of embeddings construction. The domains overlap but the functions may not agree on the common domains.